# Getting access to a color in ThemeProvider React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, themeprovider

I have a `theme` like this:

```
export const theme = {
  red: "#CF3721",
  darkGrey: "#191919",
  white: "#fff",
  blue: "#31A9B8",
};
```

and a `ThemeProvider`:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <Navigator />
</ThemeProvider>
```

How can I get access f.e. to the `red color` inside `styles` below? I tried something like this but it doesn't work well. I am using `React Native`.

```
<Component
    styles={{
            fontSize: 20,
            color: `${({ theme }) => theme.red}`,
           }}
/>
```

Comment: Where does `ThemeProvider` comes from? `react-theme-provider` library?

Comment: Yes. I mean it works for me inside f.e. styled components consts, but not inside ```styles``` attribute inside ```Component```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`react-theme-provider` library exports `useTheme` hook and `withTheme` HOC. You can access the theme context with one of those.

```js
const { ThemeProvider, withTheme, useTheme } = createTheming(defaultTheme);
```

If you're using Functional component you can use useTheme hook.

```
function App() {
  const theme = useTheme();

  return (
    <Component
      styles={{
        fontSize: 20,
        color: theme.red,
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

If you're using Class component you can use withTheme HOC.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Component
        styles={{
          fontSize: 20,
          color: this.props.theme.red,
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default withTheme(App);
```

You can look for more advanced usages in the docs. https://github.com/callstack/react-theme-provider